# xml to java object using castor

Tags: java, xml, castor, unmarshalling

What can I do to ignore the `<envelope>` and `<body>` tags in unmarshall process using Castor?

Xml examole:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<envelope>
  <header>
    <message>consultaTelefonosVigentesSocios</message>
  </header>
  <body>
    <datosTelefonosVigentesSocios>
      <listaTelefonosVigentesSocios>
        <nroInterlocutor>2000393451672</nroInterlocutor>
        <nroContrato>S6125345450573001</nroContrato>
        <nroTelefono>011-4454451-8293</nroTelefono>
        <tipoTelefono>T</tipoTelefono>
        <claseDireccion>Z001</claseDireccion>
        <descClaseDireccion>Correspondencia</descClaseDireccion>
        <marcaEstandar>X</marcaEstandar>
        <nroInterlocutorAsociadoDomicilio>200053945351672</nroInterlocutorAsociadoDomicilio>
      </listaTelefonosVigentesSocios>
      <listaTelefonosVigentesSocios>
        <nroInterlocutor>200053435391672</nroInterlocutor>
        <nroContrato>S612535430573001</nroContrato>
        <nroTelefono>011-44453551-8299</nroTelefono>
        <tipoTelefono>T</tipoTelefono>
        <claseDireccion>Z001</claseDireccion>
        <descClaseDireccion>Correspondencia</descClaseDireccion>
        <marcaEstandar/>
        <nroInterlocutorAsociadoDomicilio>20005543391672</nroInterlocutorAsociadoDomicilio>
      </listaTelefonosVigentesSocios>
      </datosTelefonosVigentesSocios>
  </body>
  <fault>
    <faultactor>servicios.page:consultaTelefonosVigentesSocios</faultactor>
  </fault>
</envelope>
```

castor mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mapping>

 <class
  name="ar.com.telefonosSocioByNroContratoService.backend.service.TelefonosVigentesSocios">
  <map-to xml="datosTelefonosVigentesSocios" />
  <field name="listaTelefonosVigentesSocios"
   type="ar.com.telefonosSocioByNroContratoService.backend.service.TelefonoVigenteSocio"
   collection="arraylist">
   <bind-xml name="listaTelefonosVigentesSocios" />
  </field>
 </class>

 <class
  name="ar.com.telefonosSocioByNroContratoService.backend.service.TelefonoVigenteSocio">
  <map-to xml="listaTelefonosVigentesSocios" />
  <field name="nroInterlocutor" type="java.lang.String">
   <bind-xml name="nroInterlocutor" node="element" />
  </field>
  <field name="nroContrato" type="java.lang.String">
   <bind-xml name="nroContrato" node="element" />
  </field>
  <field name="nroTelefono" type="java.lang.String">
   <bind-xml name="nroTelefono" node="element" />
  </field>
  <field name="tipoTelefono" type="java.lang.String">
   <bind-xml name="tipoTelefono" node="element" />
  </field>
  <field name="marcaEstandar" type="java.lang.String">
   <bind-xml name="marcaEstandar" node="element" />
  </field>
  <field name="descClaseDireccion" type="java.lang.String">
   <bind-xml name="descClaseDireccion" node="element" />
  </field>
  <field name="nroInterlocutorAsociadoDomicilio" type="java.lang.String">
   <bind-xml name="nroInterlocutorAsociadoDomicilio" node="element" />
  </field>
 </class>
</mapping>
```

Test Class:

```
public class TelefonosSocioByNroContratoServiceTest {

 @Test
 public void testUsuarioIntranetListfromXML() throws Exception{
   Mapping mapping= new Mapping();
   ClassPathResource mappingResource = 
    new ClassPathResource("/ar/com/telefonosSocioByNroContratoService/backend/service/telefonosVigenteSocios.map.xml");

      mapping.loadMapping(mappingResource.getURL());
      ClassPathResource inputExample= new ClassPathResource("ar/com/test/castor/consultaTelefonosVigentesSocios.xml");
      Reader reader = new FileReader(inputExample.getFile());

      Unmarshaller unmarshaller = new Unmarshaller(TelefonosVigentesSocios.class);
      unmarshaller.setMapping(mapping);
         TelefonosVigentesSocios telefonosVigentesSocios = (TelefonosVigentesSocios) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
         reader.close();
         Assert.assertNotNull(telefonosVigentesSocios);
         Assert.assertNotNull(telefonosVigentesSocios.getListaTelefonosVigentesSocios());
         Assert.assertTrue("se esperaba  not empty telefonos",!telefonosVigentesSocios.getListaTelefonosVigentesSocios().isEmpty());
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an input stream, you could use an XMLStreamReader (StAX) as your input.  Then advance the XMLStreamReader to the start element event for the content you mapped to.    Then have Castor unmarshal from the XMLStreamReader.

If Castor does not support StAX then I can show you how to do it with JAXB.  I lead the EclipseLink JAXB implementation (MOXy).